Не срабатывает wake on LAN
Материнская плата ASUS Z390-I Gaming, маршрутизатор Mikrotik HEXs.
В BIOS включение по LAN включено.
Раньше, когда стоял Win 10 и блок питания Corsair SF600 всё работало. Сейчас на новом месте недавно подключил наконец-то ПК по LAN кабелю и обнаружил, что уже с Windows 11 и другим БП включается в +/- 5% случаев. Сценарий на роутере стандартный "tool wol mac=тут_мак_адрес interface=etherN", где N - номер LAN порта, куда подключен ПК. Про БП и винду написал для различия, но не думаю, что это как-то влияет на выключенный ПК, но в винде в настройках адаптера тоже включил возможность просыпаться от WoL. Никаких промежуточный устройств между роутером и ПК нет.
Что может влиять на такую нестабильность? Может есть у кого предположения?

На всякий случай вопрос - а на этом "новом месте" ПК точно никогда не отключают от питания в розетке? На большинстве известных мне материнок даже кратковременная потеря питания приводит к отвалу WoL

@andreymal нет, просто переехал. Комп рядом стоит, подсветка на материнке горит... BIOS настройки сохраняет. Магия какая-то - 1 раз сработало после выключения через "завершение работы". а потом ни в какую не включается через WoL. Впервые такое
